# How does compiled Dart code communicate with the Flutter engine?

Tags: flutter, dart

With my naive and limited knowledge I would think that compiled dart code and the compiled flutter engine are linked together in the build process. If I'm correct, what patterns and mechanisms are used to achieve this perfect bond? If not, just how do they (dart code and the flutter engine) fit together?

Comment: Full flutter source code is available publicly here- https://github.com/flutter/flutter. Describing how image engines work with source code is a material for at least several hours of very specific topics. This question is the same as "How my script gives physics in unity?". Think of it more like a house. You can paint it, put furniture, get electricity or water flowing and house connects all those things. Now you see how different the topic of electricity and armored concrete are so very distant yet work together? I'd recommend separate courses for your question.

Comment: Sir, you must be correct. What do you recommend for me to learn about this topic, digging the source, or maybe could you provide some resources discussing this topic? I guess I will delete this question anyways then.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with this developer conference explaining briefly how flutter operates https://youtu.be/VUiVkDpikDI
Then learning about runtime apis and packages. Some low level kernel knowledge would be recommended to understand the topic thoroughly because all engines eventually communicate directly with the device OS, some even use hardware functionality directly without any third party interference. I don't know if you know what you're signing up for when diving into this topics but I wish you good luck. An upvote would be welcome ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch the video at least. I don't see no upvote buttons, maybe I can't upvote yet?